# Сдвиг элементов при открытии клавиатуры

Tags: android, xml, activity

Не могу понять,как сдвинуть элементы вверх,при открытии клавиатуры.Вот activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.chat.morzilka.MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
android:background="@drawable/backround" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/email_lbl"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="233dp"
    android:text="Email"

    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/passwordtxt"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />
```

Вот AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.chat.morzilka">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowNoTitle ="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:versionName="0.1"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TestActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Test_messaging"></activity>
</application>
```

Пробовал и `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden"` и `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">`

Comment: попробуйте вообще удалить android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте использовать `RelativeLayout`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Что именно вы имели ввиду?